# Large width png Raphael

Tags: raphael

I am trying to load an 8713px wide PNG in Raphael and I get an error. Is it possible to load an image this large?

Comment: It shows me an image with ? Which doesn't happened with jpg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well After An experience With My Graphic artist,

We figured that the Raphael canvas has width limitation for .png files.
The width limit is: 6600 px.

The solution I suggested is to cut the picture into two pieces (or more) and concatenate them into one big picture.

Good Luck!